# ORA-00911: invalid character Error in C# Application

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, odac

I'm created app to connect Oracle Database XE 11g with ODAC 12, and take an error called "invalid character".
This is my ConnectionString:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));User Id=hr;Password=12345;"
```

and code here

```
    private void BtnConnect_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sql = @"SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES
                    WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 120;";
        var command = new OracleCommand(sql, Connection.Connect);
        try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            var reader = command.ExecuteScalar();
            if (reader != null)
            {
                LblMessage.Content = "Connect Succeeded ";
                LblMessage.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                LblMessage.Content = "Connect Failed";
                LblMessage.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            command.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Somebody help me!

Comment: Try removing the `;` from your SQL query named `sql`.

Comment: @Ahmed Salman Tahir, oh many thanks! ^^

Answer (score 2):

Standalone queries executed from your C# application shouldn't include the semicolon `;` at the end.  If you remove that, the ORA-00911 error should go away.

Comment: we have sql file with multiline & multiple statements and ends with ; , then how to run those sql scripts in c# application

Comment: @KiranMaroju - First off, I'm not sure why a C# application would be running a SQL script as opposed to some other way of integrating SQL statements with your application unless you happen to be building a PL/SQL IDE.  Assuming that this architecture makes sense, though, you'd need some way to identify the end of a statement.  One convention that a number of tools use is to put a "/" character on a line by itself to denote the end of a statement.  Then get rid of the trailing semicolon if it is a SQL statement as opposed to a PL/SQL block.